# access dynamically created user form and controls in private sub

Tags: vba, excel

I have created user form and added controls to that dynamically in excel VBA. Now I want to count the number of text boxes that I added and also want to capture the text box value once the user enters that. Please help me with this.

```
   public dynuserform as object

   Sub answer()

   Dim options As Variant      
   Dim txtbx As MSForms.TextBox
   Dim cmdbtn As MSForms.CommandButton
   Dim txtcap As Variant
   Dim cntl As Control
   Set dynuserform = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(3)
   With dynuserform
    .Properties("Height") = 100
    .Properties("Width") = 200
   End With   
   with dynuserform    
    txtcap = "some array with dynamic size"
    For i = LBound(txtcap) To UBound(txtcap)
        Set txtbx = .designer.Controls.Add("forms.Textbox.1")
        With txtbx
            .Left = 180
            If i = 0 Then
                .Top = 30
            Else
                .Top = (30 * i) + 25
            End If
            .Height = 25
            .Width = 90
        End With
    Next i
   Set cmdbtn = .designer.Controls.Add("forms.CommandButton.1")
    With cmdbtn
        .Caption = "next"
        .Height = 25
        .Left = 190
        .Top = 80
    End With
   end with
    dynuserform.codemodule.insertlines 1, "Public ans As String"
    dynuserform.codemodule.insertlines 2, "Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()"
    dynuserform.codemodule.insertlines 3, "     if txtboxcount>1 then"
    dynuserform.codemodule.insertlines 4, "         ans = ansload"
    dynuserform.codemodule.insertlines 5, "     'Else"
    dynuserform.codemodule.insertlines 6, "         'ans = TextBox1.Value"
    dynuserform.codemodule.insertlines 7, "     'End If"     
    dynuserform.codemodule.insertlines 8, "End Sub"
    VBA.UserForms.Add(dynuserform.Name).Show
   end sub
```

Once the user click the command button I want to calculate the count of text box and i defined that in fucntion but it shows me an error object variable not set.
I want to know how to use the dynuserform object to find the count. PLease help me on this.

```
  function txtboxcount() as long
  Dim iCtrl As Long
  countTextboxes = 0
   For iCtrl = 0 To dynuserform.designer.Controls.Count - 1
      If TypeName(dynuserform.designer.Controls(iCtrl)) = "TextBox" Then
    countTextboxes = countTextboxes + 1
    Debug.Print countTextboxes
   End If
   Next iCtrl
   txtboxcount =  countTextboxes
   End Sub
```

Comment: At which line of your code does the error appear? Have you stepped through it using F8?

Is the code you have posted part of one Sub or are they two separate Sub/Functions?

Comment: break mode is not working for this code. and the answer is sub and txtboxcount is a separate function which will be called from private sub event handler. the error appear while calling the function. @SamuelEverson

Comment: `txtcap As Variant` can not have lower and upper bounds. Has this code ever run?